# Why is cv::Mat::data always pointing to a uchar?

Tags: c++, opencv, libraw

I try to read a NEF file using LibRaw and then put it in a cv::Mat. The NEF file stores data as 12bit, this means I need 16 bit, so I ought to use CV_16UC4 like this:

```
Mat img1(height, width, CV_16UC4);
```

Libraw stores data as ushort*[4], so I thought that this should work:

```
for (i = 0; i < iwidth*height; i++) {       
    img1.data[4*i+1] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][0];
    img1.data[4*i+2] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][1];
    img1.data[4*i+3] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][2];
    img1.data[4*i+4] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][3];
}
```

I also get a build error that data may be lost since a ushort to uchar conversion is going to take place, which makes sense, but still, how do I put data bigger than uchar in the data?

Answer (score 3):

If you need pointer to raw data of specific type, using `cv::Mat::ptr()` is the best practice:

```
ushort* ptr = img1.ptr<ushort>();
for (i = 0; i < iwidth*height; i++) {       
    ptr[4*i+1] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][0];
    ptr[4*i+2] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][1];
    ptr[4*i+3] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][2];
    ptr[4*i+4] = Processor.imgdata.image[i][3];
}
```

Please see [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-ptr).

Answer (score 1):

`cv::Mat::data` uses `uchar` in order avoid being a template class. In order to fill it with other image data you'll need to cast the data pointer. In your case try something like this:

```
Mat img1(height, width, CV_16UC4);
ushort * data = reinterpret_cast< ushort* >( img1.data );

for (i = 0; i < iwidth*height; i++) {
...
}
```

Alternatively, instead of changing the data pointer `img1.data` directly in your `for`-loop, you could consider using

1. the templated pixel access function `cv::Mat::at<T>()`

   ```
   img1.at<Vec4w>(y,x) = reinterpret_cast<Vec4w>(Processor.imgdata.image[i])
   ```
2. use the specialized class `Mat4w img(height, width)` and then `operator(y,x)`

   ```
   img1(y,x) = reinterpret_cast<Vec4w>(Processor.imgdata.image[i])
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Mat.data looks like a uchar, but actually it contains all the ushort data in the memory. You can simply copy the memory to your ushort array, like this:

```
memcpy(your_array, img.data, your_array_size);
```